signIn function from auth.js not working and does not even throwing any error
I am using the auth.js library, an upgraded version of of nextAuth.
in that code, i am using the signIn() function exported from auth.js file as per their official docs. this signIn() function is working properly if used in server action. when checked for what signIn() function is returning then I found out it's returning the URL provided to redirectTo filed.
here is the auth.js file

import NextAuth, { CredentialsSignin } from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import prisma from "@/database/db"
import { signinSchema } from "@/schemas/signinSchema"

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email', placeholder: 'enter your email' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                
               // validate the user email and password...
            },

        },
            
        ),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt: ({ token, user }) => {

            if (user) {
                token.id = user.id
                token.email = user.email
                token.username = user.username
                token.isVerified = user.isVerified
                token.isAcceptingMessages = user.isAcceptingMessages
            }

            return token
        }, 
        session: ({ session, token }) => {

            if (token) {
                session.user.email = token.email || ""
                session.user.id = token.id as string || ""
                session.user.isVerified = token.isVerified as boolean
                session.user.isAcceptingMessages = token.isAcceptingMessages as boolean
                session.user.username = token.username as string
            }

            return session;
        }
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: '/sign-in',
        // signOut: '/signout'
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt"
    },
    // secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET
})


/api/auth/user/signup/route.ts
import prisma from "@/database/db";
import { signupSchema } from "@/schemas/signupschema";
import { generateSixDigitOtp, sendVerificationEmail } from "@/utils/sendVerificaitonEmail";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { signIn } from "@/auth";
const saltRound = parseInt(process.env.SALT_ROUND || "");

export const POST = async (req: NextResponse) => {

    try {
        const { username, email, password } = await req.json();

        const validation = signupSchema.safeParse({ username, email, password })

        if (!validation.success && validation.error) {
            return NextResponse.json({ msg: "signup inputs are invalid", error: validation.error.message }, { status: 400 })
        }

        const userExistWithUsername = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: {
                username,
            },
            select: { id: true, username: true, email: true, isVerified: true }
        })

        if (userExistWithUsername && userExistWithUsername.isVerified) {
            return NextResponse.json({ message: "username is already taken" }, { status: 409 })
        }

        if (userExistWithUsername && !userExistWithUsername?.isVerified) {
            await prisma.user.delete({
                where: {
                    username,
                }
            })
        }

        const userExistWithEmail = await prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: { email },
            select: { id: true, email: true, isVerified: true }
        })

        if (userExistWithEmail?.isVerified) {
            return NextResponse.json({
                message: "account already exist with provided email, so please login"
            }, { status: 409 })
        }

        // if user exist with that email and its not verified then delete first account 
        if (userExistWithEmail && !userExistWithEmail.isVerified) {
            await prisma.user.delete({
                where: { id: userExistWithEmail.id }
            })
        }

        // hash the password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRound)

        const otp = generateSixDigitOtp()

        const expiryDateForOtp = new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 10 * 1000))
        // create the user in db
        const createdUser = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                email,
                username,
                password: hashedPassword,
                verifyCode: otp,
                verifyCodeExpiry: expiryDateForOtp
            },
            select: {
                email: true,
                username: true,
                id: true
            }
        })

        const { success, error } = await sendVerificationEmail(email, createdUser.username, otp)

        if (!success) {
            console.log("failed to send the email...", error)

            // delete the created user
            await prisma.user.delete({
                where: {
                    id: createdUser.id
                }
            })

            return NextResponse.json({ message: "failed to send the verification email" }, { status: 404 })
        }

        if (!createdUser) {
            return NextResponse.json({ message: 'unable to create the user' })
        }

        try {
            const signinStatus = await signIn('credentials', {
                redirect: false,
                redirectTo: '/dashboard',
                email: createdUser.email,
                password: password,
            })

            console.log('signinStatus: ', signinStatus) // http://localhost:3000/dashboard
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log('error in signin function: ', error.message)
        }

        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'created the user successfully, now verify it', createdUser }, { status: 201 })
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(error.message)
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "unable to create user!" }, { status: 500 })
    }

}

